# char(2) or enum or tinyint in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, enums, foreign-keys, query-optimization

I store CountryCode at my database and I have only 5 options to store at the column CountryCode "EG, AE, BH, QA, KW"
Should I use char(2) or tinyint or enum('EG', 'AE', 'BH', 'QA', 'KW') any why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 2-letter *standard* country_codes.

And make it `CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii`.  And debate between ascii_bin (which disallows case folding) and ascii_general_ci (for case folding).

That would be 2 bytes.

`ENUM` and `TINYINT UNSIGNED` would be only one byte, but the total number of countries is dangerously close to 256.  At that point you would need a 2-byte `ENUM` or `SMALLINT`.

An argument in favor of `CHAR(2)`:  It is human readable (mostly).  And, if you need more info about each country (full name, population, etc), you can still have a table with `PRIMARY KEY(country_code)` and easily (and efficiently) `JOIN` when needed.

Your list of 5 ccs is too long and too likely to change; don't use `ENUM`.

In general, `ENUM` should be limited to very short lists that are unlikely to change.  Also, consider *starting* the list with something like `'unknown'` instead of making the field `NULLable`.

Comment: Do you have any idea of the index performance of CHAR(2) vs INT for country codes in db tables? If common operations are to extract all entries of a specific country in the external API I'm implementing does it make a difference? I read somewhere about being careful to avoid soft collation-aware string search..

Comment: @BjornW - First of all, `CHAR(2)` is half the size of `INT`.  That, alone, makes `CHAR(2)` faster, albeit only a small amount faster.  It is a wide-spread myth that char is slower than int for lookups. The truth is that there is very little difference.  The big cost of processing is fetching (or finding in cache) the block, then finding the row in the block.  True, be careful of collations.

Comment: Thanks, that's my intuition as well (that the search itself can be as fast as ints). I'm a bit concerned about other differences though, like, db integrity (can you force an int range constraint for example at the db level, that seems impossible with general CHAR(2) for "allowed country codes") and other subtleties if any..

Comment: Also, Django (which I'm using) always uses VARCHAR unless you manually override, so I hope VARCHAR(2) is as fast (in practice) as CHAR(2) and INT :)

Comment: @BjornW - Don't worry.  You would be hard-pressed to measure a speed difference among those three options.  The way you phrased the Question implied that you wanted the details.  GMB and I gave you details.

Comment: Thanks. I should note that I'm not the OP, but this Q/A is among the first 3 on google when searching for country code representations in MySQL..

Answer (score 1):

If you're quite sure the list of accepted values is not gonna increase too much I would go with the enum to have more clean values, avoiding faulty inputs like 'Bh' 'eg' 'kW' or stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

`ENUM` s are fine, but there are drawbacks in terms of maintenance:

- listing the allowed values requires accessing the definition of the table
- adding new possible values to the list requires modifying the structure of the table
- if more than one table has a `CountryCode`  column, you need to recreate another `ENUM`

So this should be used only in cases where the list is not meant to change over time, and a single column uses it.

In all other cases, it is simpler to have a referential table that stores the values, and create foreign keys in the referencing table(s):

```
-- referential table
create table countries (countryCode varchar(2) primary key);
insert into countries values ('EG'), ('AE'), ('BH'), ('KW');

-- referencing table
create table mytable (
    id int, -- and/or other columns of the table ...
    countryCode varchar(2) references countries(countryCode)
);
```

With this technique, you get the full benefit and flexibility of foreign keys: easy maintenance, data integrity, possible indexing, nice options such as `on delete cascade`, and so on.

Comment: `VARCHAR(2)` takes at least 3 bytes.  `VAR` should be not needed _in this example_.